# urllib2: https to target via http proxy

Tags: python, https, proxy, urllib2

I am using a proxy server to connect to several target servers. Some of the target servers expect http and others expect https. My http requests work swimmingly, but urllib2 ignores the proxy handler on the https requests and sends the requests directly to the target server.

I've tried a number of different things but here is one reasonably concise attempt:

```
import urllib2
cookie_handler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor (cookielib.LWPCookieJar())
proxies = {'http': 'http://123.456.78.9/',
           'https': 'http://123.45.78.9/'}
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler (proxies)
url_opener = urllib2.build_opener (proxy_handler, cookie_handler)
request = urllib2.Request ('https://example.com')
response = url_opener.open (request)
```

I understand that urllib2 has had the ability to send https requests to a proxy server since Python 2.6.3, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using 2.7.3.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

UPDATE: The code above does work. I'm not certain why it wasn't working when I asked this question. Most likely, I had a typo in the https proxy URL.

Comment: How did you determine that the proxy isn't being used?  I just tried your sample code, pointing it at an `nc` instance as a proxy and saw a `CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.0` request as expected.

Comment: You might be better off trying to do this with the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.  Have you tried it?

Comment: James, I used WireShark to look at the actual traffic to see if the proxy handler was working. I could tell by the destination IP addresses of the outgoing messages whether they were being sent to the proxy or the ultimate recipient.

Comment: jdotjdot, initially I used Requests as my http client, but I had to replace it with urllib2 because I was having problems managing the connection pool.

Comment: I think that happens because the proxy for `https` uses HTTP (i.e. no SSL). When I debug this, I see that the code tries to make a SSL connection to the proxy (using `httplib.HTTPSConnection`).